# Como puedo usar DOMContentLoaded usando react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

Estoy empezando un projecto pero no se como saber cuando el contenido html esta cargado. Intento lo siguiente pero la consola no imprime nada:

```
<script type="text/babel">
    
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    console.log('vn sdovf');
});

</script>
```

Asi meti react en mi projecto:

```
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>  
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: @Triby. El link proporcionado apunta a esta misma página/pregunta. ¿Cual es el duplicado?

Comment: @CandidMoe, perdón, era [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/390942/como-puedo-saber-cuando-el-contenido-html-esta-cargado-con-javascript)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como puedo saber cuando el contenido html esta cargado con javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/390942/como-puedo-saber-cuando-el-contenido-html-esta-cargado-con-javascript)