# Como puedo saber cuando el contenido html esta cargado con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

estoy intentando verificar cuando el contenido html esta totalmente cargado pero la función de callback no se ejecuta nunca:

```
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>  
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
        <script type=text/babel>
              document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {console.log('DOM LOADED')});
        </script>
```

Alguien tiene idea de que esta fallando?

Comment: Quizás debas atender a este mensaje de la consola primero: **"You are using the in-browser Babel transformer. Be sure to precompile your scripts for production - https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/"**

Comment: puedes hacerlo con el evento load ejemplo : `window.onload = function(){ //tu codigo}`

Answer (score 0):

como te comentan, con JS sería : `window.onload = function(){ *codigo* }`
si usas **jquery** sería: `$(document).ready(function(){ *código* }`